# Alternative to the Web template studio extension for visual studio code?

Tags: python, html-editor, django, gui-builder, progressive-web-application

I am looking to find a free web application template builder that can autogenerate common website pages such as the landing page, a user profile page, a contact form or registration form page etc.

I am using Visual Studio IDE and I know there exists an extension called [Web Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WebTemplateStudio-dev-nightly) for it. However this template builder is pretty basic and has only three general templates to choose from. Next to that you can only choose from a couple of frontend and backend frameworks. I want to build my website with Django but the only Python framework available is Flask.

So I would like to know which alternatives exist to Web Template Studio that offer a bit more templates than WTS does. The alternatives may be free or paid and should ideally work with Django. If no alternative extensions exist then standalone alternatives are fine as well.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The example extension is not for Visual Studio, it's for Visual Studio Code. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Alejandro, I ment Visual studio code. I'll adjust the question